# Return integer for the last row in MYSQL using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm new to working with JDBC commands.  I have a database in MYSQL and each entry gets an ID.  As initially created the ID was just a static variable that I iterated when the constructor runs.  This was okay until I started deleting entries or running the program a second time.  Then I start getting collisions.  I need a way to return the highest row in the table and assign it to an integer that I can iterate.

The Query`SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table` seems to get the value that I'm looking for.  But I'm not sure of the syntax to get that value into an integer so I can return it.

```
    public int getHighestRow() {
    PreparedStatement ps;
    int highestID = 0;

    try {
        ps = getSQLDB().prepareStatement("SELECT MAX(studentID) FROM student");
        ps.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e){
        Logger.getLogger(Undergraduate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }

    if (highestID > 0) return highestID;
    else return 0;
```

I have a feeling this is very simple, but I wasn't able to find an existing answer.  Or is there a more elegant way to do this in general?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html. You should let the database generate IDs for you, instead of using a static variable. Use an auto-increment column, or a database sequence. Your technique will fail as soon as you have two programs using the database at the same time.

Comment: @JBNizet That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @JBNizet I know you're trying to encourage learning and research, but this isn't corporate production level work.  It's practice and it's a self contained program in a lab environment.  I spent 6 hours reading and researching to fix this.  I do appreciate the input though, and I'll know next time to ask for a shoe horn instead of asking for elegant when that's what I really want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL of different providers solve the retrieval of automatic generated keys differently. JDBC provides a standard solution.

Better use this JDBC solution, as it prevents mixing up those keys when insertions are done at the same time.

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = getSQLDB().prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO student(....) VALUES(?, ..., ?)",
        Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) { // Without StudentId
    ps.setString(1, name);
    ...
    ps.executeUpdate();


    try (ResultSet rsKeys = ps.getGeneratedKeys()) {
        if (rsKeys.next()) { // Only one record inserted
            int studentId = rsKeys.getInt(1); // One key generated
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e){
    Logger.getLogger(Undergraduate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
}
```

The mechanism with `try(...)`. try-with-resources, ensures that close is called automatically.

Comment: rs.getInt(1) was exactly what I needed.  Thank you!